# Receiving null value when using FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage() for handling terminated state

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am developing an app using Flutter, and I am implementing push notification using FCM with the `firebase_messaging: ^10.0.4` Flutter plugin:

I am using Firebase to send notification on mobile app while the mobile app is in terminated state. To get the notification in terminated state, I am using `FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage()` to handle the on click of notification. When the user clicks on the notification, they will be routed to a specific screen (which shows the message passed).

The issue is I am getting the notification in mobile app in terminated state, but when I click on the notification, I am not routed to the specific screen which I passed in from Firebase and `FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage()` value is getting null in message.

Please let me know If anyone have idea about this.

main.dart

```
checkFirebase() async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  // Set the background messaging handler early on, as a named top-level function
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);

  if (!kIsWeb) {
    channel = const AndroidNotificationChannel(
      'high_importance_channel', // id
      'High Importance Notifications', // title
      description: 'This channel is used for important notifications.',
      // description
      importance: Importance.max,
    );

    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

    /// Create an Android Notification Channel.
    ///
    /// We use this channel in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file to override the
    /// default FCM channel to enable heads up notifications.
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
        .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
            AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
        ?.createNotificationChannel(channel);

    /// Update the iOS foreground notification presentation options to allow
    /// heads up notifications.showFrontNotification
    await FirebaseMessaging.instance
        .setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
      alert: true,
      badge: true,
      sound: true,
    );

    FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(true);
  }
}


 
class _ProcessAppState extends State<ProcessApp> {
  Future<void> _initializeFuture;

  Future<void> _initializeServices() async {
    await Firebase.initializeApp();
    await FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(true);
    var dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    Hive.init(dir.path);
    // pass all uncaught errors to crashlytics
    Function originalOnError = FlutterError.onError;
    FlutterError.onError = (FlutterErrorDetails errorDetails) async {
      await FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordFlutterError(errorDetails);
      originalOnError(errorDetails);
    };
    // Set the background messaging handler early on, as a named top-level function
    FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);

    if (!kIsWeb) {
      channel = const AndroidNotificationChannel(
        'high_importance_channel', // id
        'High Importance Notifications', // title
        description: 'This channel is used for important notifications.',
        // description
        importance: Importance.max,
      );

/*
      flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

      /// Create an Android Notification Channel.
      ///
      /// We use this channel in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file to override the
      /// default FCM channel to enable heads up notifications.
      await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
          .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
              AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
          ?.createNotificationChannel(channel);
*/

      /// Update the iOS foreground notification presentation options to allow
      /// heads up notifications.
      await FirebaseMessaging.instance
          .setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
        alert: true,
        badge: true,
        sound: true,
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _initializeFuture = _initializeServices();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: FutureBuilder(
          future: _initializeFuture,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              reportError(
                  error: snapshot.error, stackTrace: snapshot.stackTrace);
              return Center(
                child: Text(context.translateText(key: "general_error")),
              );
            }
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
              return MyApp();
            }
            return progressBar();
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}



 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   
    return AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
      value: SystemUiOverlayStyle(
        statusBarColor: gradientTopColor,
        statusBarBrightness: Brightness.dark,
      ),
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: primaryColor,
            backgroundColor: whiteColor,
            fontFamily: 'Roboto'),
        supportedLocales: [
          Locale('en'),
          Locale('ta'),
          Locale('ml'),
          Locale('kn'),
          Locale('te'),
        ],
        localizationsDelegates: [
          // for our own localizations
          AppLocalizations.delegate,
          // localizations for all material widgets provided
          GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
          // localizations for all cupertino widgets provided
          DefaultCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
          // for rtl, ltr text directions
          GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
        ],
        locale: _locale,
        localeResolutionCallback: (deviceLocale, supportedLocales) {
          try {
            return Locale(defaultLang);
          } catch (e) {
            print(e);
            return Locale("en");
          }
        },
        // navigation analytics reporting
        // navigatorObservers: <NavigatorObserver>[observer],
        home: NotificationMessageHandler(child: LauncherScreen()),
        
        builder: EasyLoading.init(),
      ),
    );
  }
```

message_handler.dart

```
class _NotificationMessageHandlerState extends State<NotificationMessageHandler>
    with AfterLayoutMixin<NotificationMessageHandler> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // _checkForUpdate();

    var initializationSettingsAndroid =
        AndroidInitializationSettings("@mipmap/ic_launcher");
    var initializationSettings =
        InitializationSettings(android: initializationSettingsAndroid);

    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
        onSelectNotification: (payload) async {
      log("payload : $payload", name: "onSelectNotification");
      handleNotificationClick(context, jsonDecode(payload));
    });

    FirebaseMessaging.instance
        .getInitialMessage()
        .then((RemoteMessage initialMessage) async {
      log("message : $initialMessage", name: "getInitialMessage");
      handleNotificationClick(context, jsonDecode(initialMessage.toString()));
    });

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      print(message);
      showFrontNotification(message);

    });

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      handleNotificationClick(context, message.data);
    });


  }

 

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return widget.child;
  }
}
```

Comment: can you show us to the code on how you implemented it?

Comment: I have edited the question and posted  the code on how I have implemented it. Please check.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When your app is terminated and you want to navigate to another screen you need context from your MaterialApp's **navigatorKey** and also a keyword where you actually want to go, the keyword we will **"click_action"** key in the FCM request body.

I would recommend you handle your Firebase Messaging code in a separate file.

**fcm_service.dart**
This file contains route navigator in foreground, background and after app terminated, also handles notification with an image.

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

import '../main.dart';

final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

const AndroidNotificationChannel channel = AndroidNotificationChannel(
  'custom_notification_channel_id',
  'Notification',
  description: 'notifications from Your App Name.',
  importance: Importance.high,
);

Future<void> firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
}

void setupFcm() {
  var initializationSettingsAndroid = const AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');
  var initializationSettingsIOs = const IOSInitializationSettings();
  var initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
    android: initializationSettingsAndroid,
    iOS: initializationSettingsIOs,
  );

  //when the app is in foreground state and you click on notification.
  flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
      onSelectNotification: (String payload) {
        if (payload != null) {
          Map<String, dynamic> data = json.decode(payload);
          goToNextScreen(data);
        }
  });

  //When the app is terminated, i.e., app is neither in foreground or background.
  FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage().then((RemoteMessage message) {
    //Its compulsory to check if RemoteMessage instance is null or not.
    if (message != null) {
      goToNextScreen(message.data);
    }
  });

  //When the app is in the background, but not terminated.
  FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((event) {
      goToNextScreen(event.data);
    },
    cancelOnError: false,
    onDone: () {},
  );

  FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) async {
      RemoteNotification notification = message.notification;
      AndroidNotification android = message.notification?.android;
      if (notification != null && android != null) {
        if (android.imageUrl != null && android.imageUrl.trim().isNotEmpty) {
          final String largeIcon = await _base64encodedImage(
            android.imageUrl,
          );

          final BigPictureStyleInformation bigPictureStyleInformation =
          BigPictureStyleInformation(
            ByteArrayAndroidBitmap.fromBase64String(largeIcon),
            largeIcon: ByteArrayAndroidBitmap.fromBase64String(largeIcon),
            contentTitle: notification.title,
            htmlFormatContentTitle: true,
            summaryText: notification.body,
            htmlFormatSummaryText: true,
            hideExpandedLargeIcon: true,
          );

          flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
            notification.hashCode,
            notification.title,
            notification.body,
            NotificationDetails(
              android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
                channel.id,
                channel.name,
                channelDescription: channel.description,
                icon: 'custom_notification_icon',
                color: primaryColor,
                importance: Importance.max,
                priority: Priority.high,
                largeIcon: ByteArrayAndroidBitmap.fromBase64String(largeIcon),
              styleInformation: bigPictureStyleInformation,
              ),
            ),
            payload: json.encode(message.data),
          );
        }
        else {
          flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
            notification.hashCode,
            notification.title,
            notification.body,
            NotificationDetails(
              android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
                channel.id,
                channel.name,
                channelDescription: channel.description,
                icon: 'custom_notification_icon',
                color: primaryColor,
                importance: Importance.max,
                priority: Priority.high,
              ),
            ),
            payload: json.encode(message.data),
          );
        }
      }
    });

}

Future<void> deleteFcmToken() async {
  return await FirebaseMessaging.instance.deleteToken();
}

Future<String> getFcmToken() async {
  String token = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();
  return Future.value(token);
}

void goToNextScreen(Map<String, dynamic> data) {
  if (data['click_action'] != null) {
    switch (data['click_action']) {
      case "first_screen":
        navigatorKey.currentState.pushNamed(FirstScreen.routeName,);
        break;
      case "second_screen":
        navigatorKey.currentState.pushNamed(SecondScreen.routeName,);
        break;
      case "sample_screen":
        navigatorKey.currentState.pushNamed(SampleScreen.routeName,);
    }
    return;
  }
  //If the payload is empty or no click_action key found then go to Notification Screen if your app has one.
  navigatorKey.currentState.pushNamed(NotificationPage.routeName,);
}

Future<String> _base64encodedImage(String url) async {
  final http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
  final String base64Data = base64Encode(response.bodyBytes);
  return base64Data;
}
```

**main.dart**

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);

  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
      .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
      ?.createNotificationChannel(channel);

  runApp(const MyApp());
}

final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);
    
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    setupFcm();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
      onGenerateRoute: //Define your named routes.
    );
  }
}
```

Also, you need to define the default notification channel id, and optionally default notification icon, default notification color

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application>
  <meta-data
       android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
       android:value="custom_notification_channel_id" />

   <!-- Set custom default icon. This is used when no icon is set for incoming notification messages. -->
   <meta-data
       android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
       android:resource="@drawable/custom_notification_icon" />

   <!-- Set color used with incoming notification messages. This is used when no color is set for the incoming notification message.  -->
   <meta-data
       android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
       android:resource="@color/notification_icon_color" />
</application>
```

Also you can check sample FCM HTTP Request for handling **"data"** key JsonObject and **"click_action"** in it.

```
URL: https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
Request Method: POST
Header: {
  "Authorization": "key={value1}",
  "Sender": "id={value2}",
}
Request Body: {
    "registration_ids": [
        "exwlH32_S0il4ky4ZRXCrg:APA91bHp4kL-IJmtHRGFcQlhUauEY1ZiqZFfWsDkWqsB-yHDUzRVx63e8ehSirUTbSg6NqMqAAfcW16tk4dgs-NtTcCVShipGt9JWIJK_r8b4ldqFYGhzZcNF0VTiVKWzWkRQQIncCoE"
    ],
    "notification": {
        "title": "Wear Mask",
        "body": "Maintain social distance",
        "image": "https://repository-images.githubusercontent.com/31792824/fb7e5700-6ccc-11e9-83fe-f602e1e1a9f1",
        "imageUrl": "https://repository-images.githubusercontent.com/31792824/fb7e5700-6ccc-11e9-83fe-f602e1e1a9f1",
        "sound": "default"
    },
    "data": {
        "click_action": "sample_screen",
        "custom_key": "custom_value",
        "image": "https://repository-images.githubusercontent.com/31792824/fb7e5700-6ccc-11e9-83fe-f602e1e1a9f1",
        "imageUrl": "https://repository-images.githubusercontent.com/31792824/fb7e5700-6ccc-11e9-83fe-f602e1e1a9f1"
    }
}
```

Note: `registration_ids` key only takes 1000 values in the list.

In **"data"** JsonObject you can define your custom key-value pair, which will come in handy. e.g., you want to open a specific screen let's say an event_screen.dart and you need to fetch the event details from the server by event id. So you can prepare your **"data"** object accordingly

```
"data": {
        "click_action": "event_screen",
        "event_id": "23"
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the code for the _base64encodedImage() function.

Comment: @L.Goyal I have add the function(_base64encodedImage) body.

Comment: I try your code and it is working good in foreground and background states. But when application is in terminated state, I receive push, but goToNextScreen(data) is not calling. It is just open home screen and do not open click_action page.

Comment: although your answer helped me in another way but I am still facing the issue, getInitialMessage returns null when app is terminated and notification is clicked upon. Have you figured it out?

Comment: To Arham, I guess I need to look into this scenario. If you figure something let us all know.

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late to the party but may this help someone in future. I was facing the same issue and I used the above answer by Smeet Bhatt but I was still facing the same issue. What I noticed that I was clicking too fast may be `await Firebase.initializeApp();` was not finished yet. When I waited for a while, `RemoteMessage` was never null on `FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage()`.

Comment: I am facing this error. What do you mean by a period of time?